# Pass arguments with pipe in bash

Tags: bash, bash-scripting

How can I pass arguments with a pipe into the next command?

Here is my command:

```bsh
USER_EMAIL="email@gmail.com"
echo "SomePassword" | python manage.py init_admin --email=$USER_EMAIL --password= $1
```

**Any help would be appreciated**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cannot be achieved using a pipe. Use [`xargs`](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/findutils/xargs.1.en.html) instead:

```
USER_EMAIL="email@gmail.com"
echo "SomePassword" | xargs -I '{}' -- python manage.py init_admin --email=$USER_EMAIL --password={}
```

or [command substitution](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/bash/bash.1.en.html#Command_Substitution):

```
USER_EMAIL="email@gmail.com"
python manage.py init_admin --email=$USER_EMAIL --password=$(echo "SomePassword")
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I ran first command and I got `manage.py init_admin: error: unrecognized arguments: SomePassword`

Comment: That's because ```xargs``` puts a space before the passed argument (i.e. the password) by default. I modified my answer and now both suggested solutions should work.